# Missing method for Save(string) in System.Xml.Linq.Xdoument version 4.0.10.0

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm following a course on pluralsight and in the codeexample I'm supposed to be able to save a XDocument directly to file with the Save(string uri) method.

But when I try it I get an error saying cannot convert from string to System.IO.Stream.

Looking at the Class I can't find the method for Save(string uri) my version of the class is:
Assembly System.Xml.XDocument, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a

After looking at some older code which has Assembly System.XML.Linq and Version 4.0.0.0 I can find just that method.

As far as I can see I have the same using statements that the course has.

What am I missing? Or is the method removed?

Comment: Can it be that you're on a silverlight version? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: It seams that if I open a new project in Visual Studio Community 2015 with .NET Core Template and choose the Console Application (.NET Core) then that method is missing.

But If I choose the Windows template for Console Application i get that function back. 

So the easy thing is just start a new project and move the code. Anyone else get the same issue or should I reinstall the program since I might have done something wrong when installing?

Comment: .NET Core is a stripped down version so that is a similar scenario as was with Silverlight. using the other project template gives you the full blown framework which seems a better option.

Comment: Well now it works, thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure. Don't forget to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by starting a new project and using the Windows template for a console application instead of the .NET Coretemplate that I've used before.

Don't know if there is a solution where you can use the .NET Core template and add extra functionality afterwards.

But that's how I solved it with the help from rene.